# Redux Thunk action not executing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm using React with Redux and Thunk as middleware to handle async actions. I have a button where when a user clicks it, it should logout the user. Currently when I click the button nothing happens. I've added a `console.log` in the `attemptLogout` but even that isn't triggering... I can't figure out why, was hoping someone could review my code and provide some feedback.

**NavProfile.js**

```
const onLogout = () => {
  attemptLogout();
};

<Menu.Item key={menuItem.legth + 1} onClick={onLogout}>
    <span>
        <LogoutOutlined className="mr-3" />
        <span className="font-weight-normal">Logout</span>
    </span>
</Menu.Item>
```

**redux/actions/Auth.js**

```
export const logout = () => ({
  type: LOGOUT,
});
```

**redux/reducers/Auth.js**

```
const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  isAuthenticated: false,
  loading: true,
  error: {},
};

const auth = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    ...
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**redux/reducers/User.js**

```
const initialState = {
  user: null,
  loading: true,
  error: {},
};

const user = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    ...
    case LOGOUT:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**redux/thunks/Auth.js**

```
// Logout User
export const attemptLogout = () => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log('Logout');
  dispatch(logout());
  dispatch(push('/auth/login'));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispatch `attemptLogout`. Otherwise the thunk never passed through redux middleware and is never called.

```
const onLogout = () => {
  dispatch(attemptLogout());
};
```

To access dispatch you can use the hook in your menu/menu item component. Something like:

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

function MenuExample() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onLogout = () => {
    dispatch(attemptLogout());
  };

  ...
}
```